# Cannot mutate a Python randomly generated list

Tags: python, arrays

I'm just playing around with a local k8s cluster and created a simple app to containerize.
I just want to print a reversed array.
Disclaimer: I might be using the words "lists" and "arrays" interchangeably here :)

So I defined two utility functions: one to generate lists with random int values and one to reverse said lists.

```
from random import randint

def reverse_array(input):
    i=0
    arr_length = len(input)
    last_index = arr_length - 1
    while i < arr_length / 2:
        temp = input[i]
        input[i] = input[last_index - i]
        input[last_index - i] = temp
        i=i+1
    return input

def generate_random_array(max_iteration):
    return [randint(0, 100) for _ in range(0, max_iteration)]
```

Both methods have unit tests, so I know they're working as intended

then I execute them in the main app:

```
import util.misc as misc
from time import sleep

while True:
    input_arr = misc.generate_random_array(5)
    reversed_arr = misc.reverse_array(input_arr)
    
    # adding manual and control only for debugging
    manual = [1, 2, 3]
    control= misc.reverse_array(manual)
    print(f"your original array is {input_arr}")
    print(f"your reversed array is {reversed_arr}")
    print(f"control is {control}")
    sleep(1)
```

Oddly enough, the application's output shows `reversed_arr` actually has the same order as `input_arr`, but `control` is correctly reversed.

```
your original array is [27, 95, 0, 91, 13]
your reversed array is [27, 95, 0, 91, 13]
control is [3, 2, 1]
```

What is going on here? It seems that arrays produced by `generate_random_array` are actually immutable

Comment: How can you tell if a _random_ array is reversed or not?

Comment: The "random" part is the array generation. Once generated, its values are not going to change on their own.
Debugging the app, I CAN see the generated array being reversed correctly, but the actual return value of the method ends up having the same order from the start

Comment: this working fine, where you generate value from random function and pass it to reverse one.

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by " where you generate value from random function and pass it to reverse one"

A random array is generated, so it migh be [1, 4, 6, 8, 9] or [2, 3, 6, 5, 2], and this randomly generated array is being passed to the reverse function. The reverse IS reversing it, but the return value of the reverse is still the array with the same order. Wheras the control array IS reversed.

Comment: Your `reverse_array` mutates its input, hence you lose the original array. You are comparing the reversed array with itself.

Comment: well i copied your function , add it in terminal, generated a random array and pass that to the reverse function and it was giving result as expected

Comment: You are only printing twice the reversed version - that's a problem with random data, you can't recognize it. Note that you wouldn't have this problem if your `reverse` function returned a new list instead of modifying the original one, which the basic, quick, standard method does: `def reverse_array(inp): return inp[::-1]`

Comment: If you print `input_arr` *before* calling `reverse_array(input_arr)`, you'll see the actual original list.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille there isn't anything inherently wrong with mutating an array instead of returning a new one, and in real data intensive applications, it might be preferable to mutate a huge array instead of creating a copy.
Of course it's irrelevant for a trivial application such as this, and yes, I overlooked the fact I was printing the contents of the same memory address, I'm just saying the problem here isn't really that the input is being mutated and that there isn't anything inherently wrong with mutating vs returning a new value.

Comment: @Dasph Yes, but the OP still wants to use the original *and* the reversed versions of his list at the end of his code, so he needs two different ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code actually reverses the array, you can see that by printing out the original array before reverse:

```
input_arr = generate_random_array(5)
print(f"your original array is {input_arr}")

reversed_arr = reverse_array(input_arr)
print(f"your reversed array is {reversed_arr}")
```

Output:

```
your original array is [15, 69, 31, 14, 34]
your reversed array is [34, 14, 31, 69, 15]
```

What happens is you're mutating (reversing) the original array and also returning a link to the same object as "reversed" array, therefore you can't see the difference when printing after the reverse.

You can also notice that if you change the reversed array, the original will change too. They're just links to the same object.

Comment: It's easy to fix too, just add `input = input.copy()` as the first line of `reverse_array`.  Then it won't mutate its input anymore.

Comment: I explicitly wanted it to mutate its input instead of returning a new list

Comment: Then `reverse_array` should return `None` instead of the updated list, to reinforce that the reference to the argument is the only way to see the result.